# Marshal/Unmarshal "enum" to DynamoDB using golang

Tags: go, enums, amazon-dynamodb, marshalling

I have the following `PartnerType` "enum" struct in go:

```golang
// PartnerType enum
type PartnerType int

const (
    // PartnerTypeUnknown should never happen
    PartnerTypeUnknown PartnerType = iota

    // PartnerTypeTest test
    PartnerTypeTest
)

func (t PartnerType) String() string {
    names := [...]string{
        "UNKNOWN",
        "TEST"}

    if t < PartnerTypeUnknown || t > PartnerTypeTest {
        return names[0]
    }
    return names[t]
}

// MarshalJSON for enum
func (t PartnerType) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    s := t.String()
    return json.Marshal(s)
}

// UnmarshalJSON for enum
func (t *PartnerType) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    *t = PartnerTypeUnknown
    return nil
}

// MarshalText implements the text marshaller method
func (t *PartnerType) MarshalText() ([]byte, error) {
    return []byte(t.String()), nil
}

// UnmarshalText implements the text unmarshaller method
func (t *PartnerType) UnmarshalText(text []byte) error {
    *t = PartnerTypeUnknown
    return nil
}

// Partner entity
type Partner struct {
    ID   string `dynamodbav:"PK,omitempty"`
    Foo string `dynamodbav:"SK,omitempty"`
    PartnerType              PartnerType    `dynamodbav:",omitempty,string"`
}
```

When doing a `dynamodbattribute.MarshalMap()` I'd like my `PartnerType` to be stored as a string.  The [dynamodbav](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/dynamodb/dynamodbattribute/#Marshal) struct tag allows you to store an int as a string (`dynamodbav:",omitempty,string"`) however it is not calling my defined `.String()` or `Marshal/Unmarshal` implementations.

Said another way, it stores `PartnerTypeTest` as `"1"` not `"TEST"`.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For dynamodb you can implement your marshaler/unmarshaler for enums

Try the following:

```
// MarshalDynamoDBAttributeValue for ddb
func (t PartnerType) MarshalDynamoDBAttributeValue(av *dynamodb.AttributeValue) error {
    s := t.String()
    av.S = &s
    return nil
}

// UnmarshalDynamoDBAttributeValue implements the Unmarshaler interface
func (t *PartnerType) UnmarshalDynamoDBAttributeValue(av *dynamodb.AttributeValue) error {
    // val := aws.StringValue(av.S)

    *t = PartnerTypeUnknown
    return nil
}
```